# Create file and its parent directory

Tags: command-line, files

I know that `touch` command creates a file:

```
touch test1.txt
```

but how I can create a file and its full path?

for example my desktop contains nothing:

```
~/Desktop/$ ls
~/Desktop/$
```

and I want to create 1.txt in `~/Desktop/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1.txt`.
Can I do this with a simple command like:

```
$ touch ~/Desktop/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1.txt
```

instead of create full path manually and then create the file?

Comment: From the answer below: `mkdir -p parent/child && touch $_/file.txt ` by @francis

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`touch` is not able to create directories, you need `mkdir` for that.

However, `mkdir` has the useful `-p`/`--parents` option which creates a full directory structure.

From `man mkdir`:

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

So the command you need in your specific situation is:

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/ && touch ~/Desktop/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1.txt
```

---

If you think you will need this more often and don't want to type the path twice every time, you can also make a Bash function or a script for it.

- Bash function (append this line to `~/.bashrc` to persitently have it available to your user, otherwise it will vanish again when you exit your terminal):

  ```
  touch2() { mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && touch "$1" ; }
  ```

  It can be simply used like this:

  ```
  touch2 ~/Desktop/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1.txt
  ```
- Bash script (store it in `/usr/local/bin/touch2` using sudo to make it available for all users, else in `~/bin/touch2` for your user only):

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" &&
      touch "$1"
  ```

  Don't forget to make the script executable using `chmod +x /PATH/TO/touch2`.

  After that you can also run it like this:

  ```
  touch2 ~/Desktop/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1.txt
  ```

Comment: can I edit original `touch ` command and add switch `-p` to it?

Comment: @HeshmatKhah It should be possible, but it is not recommended to shadow system executables with your own scripts or functions. You could use the name `touch-p` (no space!) instead of `touch2`, if you prefer the "p", but I would not attempt to replace the original command.

Comment: Note that you can use suffix removal instead of `dirname` as well , i.e. you could do `mkdir -p "${1%/}" && touch  "$1"` , same as https://askubuntu.com/a/928544/295286

Comment: Extra question: if I try to execute `touch2` from another script as `bash x.sh` or `./x.sh`, then bash says `touch2: command not found`. What is the root cause? How to fix? UPD: I've already tried: `#!/bin/bash -i`, `shopt -s expand_aliases`, `source ~/.bashrc`. Nothing worked for me. So, I've had to put `touch2() { mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && touch "$1" ; }` directly into the `x.sh`.

Answer (score 29):

```
mkdir -p parent/child && touch $_/file.txt
```

Comment: this answer should have more votes than 4. smart one.

Comment: IMHO, any explanations for this answer would be good.

Comment: This link explains how this magic happens https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280557/422527

Comment: ☝️ this answer should be accepted, not the one right now (thanks @francis)

Answer (score 24):

One can use `install` command with `-D` flag.

```
bash-4.3$ install -D /dev/null mydir/one/two

bash-4.3$ tree mydir
mydir
└── one
    └── two

1 directory, 1 file
bash-4.3$
```

If we have multiple files, we might want to consider using a list of items(note, remember to quote items with spaces), and iterating over them:

```
bash-4.3$ for i in mydir/{'subdir one'/{file1,file2},'subdir 2'/{file3,file4}} ; do 
> install -D /dev/null "$i"
> done
bash-4.3$ tree mydir
mydir
├── one
│   └── two
├── subdir 2
│   ├── file3
│   └── file4
└── subdir one
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

Or alternatively with array:

```
bash-4.3$ arr=( mydir/{'subdir one'/{file1,file2},'subdir 2'/{file3,file4}} )
bash-4.3$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do  install -D /dev/null "$i"; done
bash-4.3$ tree mydir
mydir
├── one
│   └── two
├── subdir 2
│   ├── file3
│   └── file4
└── subdir one
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

Comment: WIth this approach, the new file gets executable permissions by default. To give it the same permissions it would get with touch, one can use `install -m 644 -D /dev/null <filepath>`

Answer (score 4):

For this purpose you can create your own function, example below:

```
$ echo 'mkfile() { mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && touch "$1" ;  }' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ mkfile ./fldr1/fldr2/file.txt
```

First we insert a function to the end of ~/.bashrc file using echo command. The -p flag in function allows to create the nested folders, such as fldr2 from our example. Finally we update the file with source command and eventually execute recently created mkfile command

Answer (score 1):

I use [The Fuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) to make my life easier with this command. It's a CLI tool that corrects errors in previous console commands.

```
$ touch a/folder/that/does/not/exist/file
touch: cannot touch 'a/folder/that/does/not/exist/file': No such file or directory
$ fuck
mkdir -p a/folder/that/does/not/exist && touch a/folder/that/does/not/exist/file [enter/↑/↓/ctrl+c]
$ ls a/folder/that/does/not/exist/file
a/folder/that/does/not/exist/file
```