# Creating a file within a folder then writing to that file with SSH

Tags: 18.04, bash, ssh

I am trying to use write a script that uses SSH to create a new directory and write to a text file in it. I've got 1 master on a network, and then 3 nodes that I want to create the directory on. These 4 machines are hosted on VMware.

```
#node1
ssh node1@192.168.1.102 'sudo touch /temp_dirname/host.txt'
ssh node1@192.168.1.102 'echo "node1" | sudo tee /temp_dirname/host.txt'

#node2
ssh node1@192.168.1.103 'sudo touch /temp_dirname/host.txt'
ssh node1@192.168.1.103 'echo "node1" | sudo tee /temp_dirname/host.txt'

#node3
ssh node3@192.168.1.104 'sudo touch /temp_dirname/host.txt'
ssh node3@192.168.1.104 'echo "node1" | sudo tee /temp_dirname/host.txt'
```

When I run this I get different errors for each node... for nodes 1 and 2 I get

```
touch: cannot touch '/temp_dirname/host.txt': no such file or directory
```

and

```
tee: temp_dirname/host.txt: no such file or directory
```

and node 3 I get:

```
touch: setting times of '/temp_dirname/ no such file or directory
```

and

```
tee: temp_dirname/host.txt: no such file or directory
```

I am absolutely confused with this as I thought `touch` created files - so why is it no such file or directory.

Comment: Possibly related: [Create file and its parent directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800845/create-file-and-its-parent-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `/temp_dirname` doesn't exist, you can create it with `mkdir -p /temp_dirname`.

`-p` works with any arbitrary depth, creating directories as required.

Comment: This works! I could have sworn I tried this earlier with no avail... One question, I do have @vintnes is that `/temp_dirname` doesn't show up when I do either `ls` or `ls -a`

Comment: `ls` defaults to your current working directory -- usually `/home/$USER` by default. Specify path, as in `ls -a /` or `ls -a /temp_dir` or change your working directory with `cd`. Get comfortable with `man`!